# Fix the solidify and cloth simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

When I use cloth before solidify, I get ton of overlaping and bad result. When I use solidify before cloth I get better result, but cloth thicknes changes as both sides of geometry are animated.

Can I put a solidify before cloth and still have the exact cloth thickness after cloth sim?
Thank you
Mladen

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most of the time Solidify comes after Cloth, maybe increase the Self Collision distance value so that it works correctly?

Comment: I tried, but it starts to clump up when I up this value and the mesh still goes through it self. I am making miniatures for 3D print, and this is quite important to work.

Comment: In fact I cannot get collision to work on both sides of the cloth when solidify is after cloth. Best I can get is to set solidify offset to 0 and play with self colision distance, but it's not so good.

Comment: Maybe share the object itself so that we can try?

Comment: @mladen: welcome to BSE. Unfortunately we cannot help you without a minimum of required information. Since you provided nearly no information about your settings, pls provide blend file so we don't have to ask for details in the comments. thx.

Comment: First image is solidify => clothes = uneven edges and thicknes, but no overlap

Comment: Second image is clothe => solidify = good thicknes, but overlap. Ofset set to 0, with best self colision setting I can get. I even tried to scale the object bigger or smaller.